# When is 'if' not necessary?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

In some scripts, I've seen `if` conditional statements written as:

```
if [ some_conditional_statement ]; then
    # do stuff
fi
```

or

```
[ some_conditional_statement ] && #do stuff
```

Is the second example equivalent (do stuff portion will only execute if the conditional is true), but only useful when you only need to perform one command such as:

```
[ -f "/path/to/some/file" ] && . /path/to/some/file
```

Or is there another difference I am missing?

Comment: Side note: you may want to read about [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) to know more about `&&`.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith I believe I understand the `&&` operation already, in the second example, the first part is evaluated, and if true, the second part (right side of the `&&` is evaluated, which executes the code), if false, being a logical AND operation, it shorts and skips evaluation of the right side. This appears, to me, to be equivalent of the first example using the `if then` syntax, but has the downside of only being able to evaluate one command instead of multiples inside the `if` block. Then again, I suppose you could chain `&&`'s together... Am I missing anything?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators)

Comment: I don't think it is an outright dup - it's more about difference between `&&` and `if command; then`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The if-clause will execute whatever is in between `then` and `fi` if the expression after the `if` is true, which in shell terms mean that its exit value is zero. You can use a command or the brackets which is just a short form for the `test` command. The `a && b` construct means: "evaluate a and if its true also evaluate b". So your two examples are equivalent, but the if-clause is more readable and can be used to group several commands.

Comment: hmm, that is what I had suspected. Comes down to a readability issue depending on what you are doing (in my case, checking if files or directories exist, and if not, making them, so the `&&` construct is more readable than a bunch of cascading `if` statements). I just wanted to be sure bash wasn't doing anything else with this alternate syntax.

Comment: I would not consider `&&` as an alternate syntax to if, it is really what it looks like, that is "and". You could for instance do: `if echo && echo; then echo ok; fi`. The reason it can be used as an if-statement is the short circuiting.

Comment: Personally, don't feel `if` adds any readability for simple logic constructs, and prefer it in keeping code short. For longer/more-complicated blocks of code it obviously helps separate out what's getting executed as a result of a condition. It's also worth noting that there are a number of languages where short circuit evaluation is in many cases clearly preferable to `if/else` constructs, i.e. `perl`.

Answer (score 5):

OK, I presume that you understand that `[ condition ]`
(or `[[ condition ]]` in bash)
is, essentially, a command that has no side effects,
but that evaluates the condition and gives an appropriate exit status. 
You mentioned chaining `&&`s together. 
You can do that;

```
A  &&  B  &&  C
```

is equivalent to

```
if A
then
    if B
    then
        C
    fi
fi
```

But you seem to be asking how to do

```
if A
then
    B
    C
fi
```

You can do that with

```
A  &&  (B; C)
```

or

```
A  &&  { B; C;}
```

Notes:

- The parentheses give you a subshell; i.e., commands `B` and `C` run in a child process. 
  Therefore,
  commands like variable assignments or `cd` will have no effect on the parent shell. 
  Commands in braces run in the same process as the `A` command.
- In the brace syntax,
  there *must* be a space after the `{`, 
  and there *must* be a `;` (or an `&` or a newline) before the `}`.

### My opinion:

I strongly recommend using the `if`-`then`-`else` syntax, for improved readability.

Comment: FWIW, apart from the presentation and clarity issues, there's also the odd difference between `if A; then B; C; fi` and `A && { B; C; }` that if the test `A` _fails_, the exit status of the whole `if` is zero (truthy), but with `&&` it's the falsy non-zero status that `A` actually returned.