# Why doesn't this fairly simple "if" work?

Tags: bash

Here is my script:

```
if [[ "$(echo "$2" | sed 's/.two//g')" == "load" ]] && [[ "$1" == "Decrypt" ]] || [[ "$(echo "$2" | sed 's/.two//g')" == "load" ]] && [[ "$1" == "Encrypt" ]] 
then
    key=aNXlye1tGbd0uP
else
    if [ -z "$key" ]
    then
        key="$2"
    fi
fi
```

It's supposed to look for the second argument, remove potential `.two`, and then compare it to `load`, if it is `load` then it should set `key` to `aNXlye1tGbd0uP`. However, this doesn't work. This is what it looks like when I run it.

```
pskey Decrypt load (some string)
```

Here is the output from `bash -x`:

```
++ echo load
++ sed s/.two//g
+ [[ load == \l\o\a\d ]]
+ [[ Decrypt == \D\e\c\r\y\p\t ]]
+ [[ Decrypt == \E\n\c\r\y\p\t ]]
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ key=load
```

However, If I remove whats after `[[ "$1" == "Decrypt" ]]`, it works. What is wrong with that line?

Comment: The part you're asking about specifically is working as intended.  `set -x; export FOO="Decrypt"; [[ "$FOO" == "Decrypt" ]] && echo "yep"` works as expected (i. e. `yep` is echoed).  If it weren't, you'd not even be getting to the comparison to `Encrypt` which occurs later in the conditional chain.  For the substring comparison, rather than spawning `sed`, I might look into `[[ "load" == "${2/.two/}" ]]` for example.

Comment: @DopeGhoti, yeah but if remove I what's after `[[ "$1" == "Decrypt" ]]`, the key becomes what I want it to become.

Comment: That is very far from a "simple" `if`. What are you expecting it to do? You have various AND conditions combined with OR. I think you expect it to group some of them together but you need to tell us how. Your `if` statement boils down to `if A && B || C && D`. I _think_ you are after `if (A && B) || (C && D)`, is that correct?

Comment: (1) As part of your debugging, you should have replaced `"$(echo "$2" | sed 's/.two//g')"` with `$2`, leaving the `if` expression as `[[ "$2" == "load" ]] && [[ "$1" == "Decrypt" ]] || [[ "$2" == "load" ]] && [[ "$1" == "Encrypt" ]]`, to verify that the `sed` complication wasn’t causing the problem.  Having done so, you should have posted the simplified version in your question, so we wouldn’t have to scroll your script (horizontally) to read it.  Also, maybe, switch the order, so the `$1` tests appear before the `$2` tests (for readability).  (2) Please indent your code in a readable style.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for something like this:

```
if [[ "$(echo "$2" | sed 's/.two//g')" == "load" && "$1" == "Decrypt" ]] || 
   [[ "$(echo "$2" | sed 's/.two//g')" == "load" && "$1" == "Encrypt" ]]
then
    ...
fi
```

Note that you could also simplify the whole thing to:

```
 if [[ "$(echo "$2" | sed 's/.two//g')" == "load" && "$1" =~ (De|En)crypt ]]; then ...
```

Comment: The reason the original code doesn't work is because bash gives `&&` and `||` equal precedence. `A && B || C && D` is evaluated like `((A && B) || C) && D`, whereas in every other sane programming language it is `(A && B) || (C && D)`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman: This comment would be more appropriately placed on the question itself, rather than on terdon’s answer — I’m pretty sure that terdon already understands this, and your tack-on doesn’t really clarify this answer.  Or you could have put it on [BinaryZebra’s answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/252021/80216).

Comment: @JohnKugelman is mostly correct: Boolean algebra says that `and` is evaluated before `or`, but it unix-shell, C, C++, C♯, java, java-script, and some others, they are evaluated left to right. They are also guaranteed to be lazy evaluated (as soon as the computer knows the answer it will stop). This is on purpose and is useful: it allows you to say for example ( a is a character string && length of a > 4 && 3rd letter of a is 'b' ) without causing an error when evaluating the latter parts.

Comment: @JohnKugelman All [POSIX shells do this on AND/OR Lists (2.9.3 Lists).](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03) `The operators "&&" and "||" shall have equal precedence and shall be evaluated with left associativity`

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
if    [[ "$(echo "$2" | sed 's/.two//g')" == "load" ]] &&
      [[ "$1" == "Decrypt" ]]                          ||
      [[ "$(echo "$2" | sed 's/.two//g')" == "load" ]] &&
      [[ "$1" == "Encrypt" ]]
```

The sed call could be simplified to just: `${2%?two}` if the replacement is at the end of the variable `$2`. Please understand that the "any character" that the dot (.) represents in sed, is equivalent to the question mark (?) in patterns (thanks @terdon). If the replacement needs to be done for all occurrences of `.two`, then we should use: `"${2//?two}"`.
Then we get this shorter version:

```
if [[ "${2//?two}" == "load" ]]  &&  [[ "$1" == "Decrypt" ]]  ||
   [[ "${2//?two}" == "load" ]]  &&  [[ "$1" == "Encrypt" ]]
```

which is doing `if A && B || C && D`.

When A is true (load = load) B is executed.
If B is true (Decrypt = Decrypt) the following `||` phrase (C) is skipped and
then D is executed (Decrypt = Encrypt).
Which results (the last command executed) in a `false` value.
Then the `else` is executed .....

I suspect that what you mean is `if ( A && B ) || ( C && D )` which, as `A` is the same as `C`,  is exactly the same as `if ( A && B ) || ( A && D )`,
which can be simplified (using the [distributive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property)) to
 `if A && ( B || D )`:

```
if      [[ "${2//?two}" == "load" ]] &&
      ( [[ "$1" == "Decrypt" ]]   ||  [[ "$1" == "Encrypt" ]]  );
then
      key=aNXlye1tGbd0uP
else
      if    [ -z "$key" ]
      then  key="$2"
      fi
fi
```

The `-z` test for "$key" could be simplified to a simple expansion: key="${key:-$2}"

And, maybe, it would be more readable (IMO) like this:

```
if A; then
      if   B || D; then
```

Which translates to this:

```
if           [[ "${2//?two}" == "load" ]]
then   if    [[ "$1" == "Decrypt" ]]   ||  [[ "$1" == "Encrypt" ]]
       then  key=aNXlye1tGbd0u
       else  key="${key:-$2}"
       fi
else         key="${key:-$2}"
fi
```

Or could be, using @terdon’s idea, written as this:

```
if           [[ "${2//?two}" == "load" ]] &&
             [[ "$1" =~ (De|En)crypt ]]
then         key=aNXlye1tGbd0u
else         key="${key:-$2}"
fi
```

Please Note that this is also equivalent:

```
if       [[  ( "${2//?two}" == "load" ) &&
             ( "$1" =~ (De|En)crypt )
         ]]
then         key=aNXlye1tGbd0u
else         key="${key:-$2}"
fi
```

The parenthesis are not strictly needed, but added to enforce the idea that inside `[[` test you could give structure to your tests adding whitespace (tab, space, newline) and parenthesis. That does not work the same in `[` tests.

Answer (score 1):

terdon’s statement «That is very far from a “simple” `if`.» is an
understatement.  As [John Kugelman pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/252011/#comment434593_252015),
`&&` and `||` have equal precedence, and are handled from left to right. 
[BinaryZebra offered the idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/252021/80216) of translating Boolean expressions
into cascading `if` statements.  My best attempt to “simplify”

```
if A && B || C && D
then
        result=0
else
        result=1
fi
```

is

```
if A
then
        if B
        then
                if D                                        ←
                then
                        result=0
                else
                        result=1
                fi
        else
                if C
                then
                        if D
                        then
                                result=0
                        else
                                result=1
                        fi
                else
                        result=1
                fi
        fi
else
        if C
        then
                if D
                then
                        result=0
                else
                        result=1
                fi
        else
                result=1
        fi
fi
```

***Very far*** from simple. 
As you may be able to see from the above,
the reason why it doesn’t work is that,
(on the marked line) if A and B are both true,
it still goes on to test D (`[[ "$1" == "Encrypt" ]]`).

As BinaryZebra shows without mentioning,
you *can* use some math-like notation in sh/bash scripts; e.g., you can say

```
if (A && B) || (C && D)
then
  ︙
```

or, in the slightly simplified version of your code,

```
if ( [["$2" == "load" ]] && [[ "$1" == "Decrypt" ]] )  ||  ( [[ "$2" == "load" ]] && [[ "$1" == "Encrypt" ]] )
then
  ︙
```

A feature of this is that code in parentheses is run in a subshell. 
If that’s a problem, you can use braces instead:

```
if { [["$2" == "load" ]] && [[ "$1" == "Decrypt" ]] ; }  ||  { [[ "$2" == "load" ]] && [[ "$1" == "Encrypt" ]] ; }
then
  ︙
```

Note that there must be a `;` before the `}`
(optionally separated by whitespace),
and there must be whitespace before and after the `{`, and after the `}`.

> **Of course you should use the techniques presented in the other answers for *simplifying* your test, such as *not* doing the same test on `$2` twice.**

Related: [Pipes & redirection binding precedence with disjuncts,
conjuncts etc.?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/163479/80216) and [When is “if” not necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/158676/80216)

Comment: Or, you could do the parenthesis inside the `[[` test:  `[[ (A && B) || (C && D) ]]`, or better the simplified one: `[[ A && (B || D) ]]` Which will translate to `[[ "$(echo "$2" | sed 's/.two//g')" == "load" && ( "$1" == "Decrypt" ||  "$1" == "Encrypt") ]]`. In this case there is no sub-shell called. It is all shell evaluations.

Comment: No, this really is very simple. This is what `case` does. When you can branch conditionally, that's how you can make these things simple. Just look at my answer - it does what is required. And I'm fairly certain the `sed` is overkill, but because there is no example of input to output there really isnt anyway to know. `if` is very bad here, though.

Comment: i guess w/ `if`: `two=;if  for m in De En; do [ "${m}crypt" = "$1" ] && [ load = "${two:=$(echo "$2"|sed 's/.two//g')}" ] && break; done; then key=string; else key=${key:-$2}; fi`

Comment: the thing about a left-associative, equally-precedented boolean eval is that you can directly AND an OR. you couldnt do that otherwise. what that means is: *`this or that or the other thing and do true and do true and do true or do whatever`*. its just left right - *`OR OR OR AND AND AND`*. with the short-cirtcuit it cuts possibilities down by a whole lot - but every operator needs considering - and mixing them cancels their effects - because AND/OR *are* opposites.

Answer (score -1):

In the first place:

```
[[ $1:$2 =~ ^(En|De)crypt:(.two)*load(.two)*$ ]] && echo conditions met
```

But your `if` boolean logic is backwards:

```sh
#sed    #En=$1   #De=$1
true  && false || true    # passes your logic
true  && true  || NA      # passes your logic
false && NA    || false   # fails  your logic
false && NA    || true    # fails  your logic
```

The second `&&` is omitted here because its not a factor - its result is always the same as the first. Its a noop in this logic chain.

That doesn't work well - the one failure case breaks your statement. In any of these cases in which the first test is false, you wind up ORing its return as opposed to that of the (De|En)crypt tests. And, in fact, the first of these doesn't even occur because it is short-circuited by the *load* return.
So you want to do the ORs first, and take advantage of the short-circuit by delaying the expensive command substitution until you definitely need to test for it:

```sh
#En=$1  #De=$1   #sed
false || false && NA
false || true  && false
false || true  && true
true  || NA    && false
true  || NA    && true
```

All of these pass your logic and the command substitution isn't even attempted if both of the first two statements are false.

Here it is portably w/ `case` and `expr`:

```
case  ${2%oad*}:${1%crypt}  in
(:${key:=$2}*|*ad*|*:"$1")  ;;
(*l:De|*l:En)  expr " $2" :  \
" \(\(.two\)*\(load\)*\)*$" &&
     key=aNXlye1tGbd0uP
esac >/dev/null
```

And `if`:

```
if   [ Encrypt = "$1" -o Decrypt = "$1" ] &&
     expr " $2" : " \(.two\)*load\(.two\)*$"
then key=$newkey
else key=${key:-$2}
fi   >/dev/null
```

And just `expr` and `&&||`, because the `if` doesn't do much for you:

```
expr   > /dev/null       \
 "${#1} ${1%crypt}  $2" :\
 "7 \(\(De\)*\(En\)*\) ""\
 \(.two\)*load\(.two\)*$" &&
key=$newkey || key=${key:-$2}
```

Perhaps w/ `grep`:

```
grep -xqE '(En|De)crypt:(.two)*load(.two)*' \
<<VAR &&   key=$newkey || key=${key:-$2}
${1##*:*}:$2
VAR
```